# ec2へphpでftpアップロードができません

Tags: php

php7の`ftp_put`を使いec2へファイルのアップロードをしようとしているのですが、以下のワーニングが出てきてしまいファイルのアップロードに失敗してしまいます。

出ているワーニングはどういったエラーなのでしょうか。
又、問題があるのはコードなのかサーバー側なのか…
ご相談よろしくお願いします

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Warning: ftp_put(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115) in /var/www/test/ftp_operate.php on line 32

Warning: ftp_put(): Switching to Binary mode. in /var/www/test/ftp_operate.php on line 32
```

**ソースコード**

```
<?php
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

// サーバ

define("FTP_COPY_CONNECT_HOST","***.**.*.**");
define("FTP_COPY_LOGIN_USER","testuser");
define("FTP_COPY_LOGIN_PASSWD","testpass");

$fpath = "/var/www/test/iLog201900314.zip";

$ftp = new FtpOperate();
$ftp->startCopy($fpath);

class FtpOperate
{

    public function startCopy($fpath)
    {
        // FTPサーバ接続
        // デフォルトポート0(21),120秒でタイムアウト
        //$ftp = ftp_connect(FTP_COPY_CONNECT_HOST, 0, 120);
        $ftp = $this->connect();
        if(!$ftp)
        {
            echo "接続失敗";
            return false;
        }

//        ftp_set_option($ftp, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);
        ftp_pasv($ftp,true);
        if(!ftp_put($ftp, basename($fpath), $fpath, FTP_BINARY))
        {
            echo "アップロード失敗";
            ftp_close($ftp);
            return false;
        }
        ftp_close($ftp);
        return true;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        // FTPサーバ接続
        // デフォルトポート0(21),120秒でタイムアウト
        $ftp = ftp_connect(FTP_COPY_CONNECT_HOST, 0, 120);
        if(!$ftp)
        {
            echo "接続失敗";
            return false;
        }
        // FTPログイン
        if(!ftp_login($ftp, FTP_COPY_LOGIN_USER, FTP_COPY_LOGIN_PASSWD))
        {
            echo "ログイン失敗";
            ftp_close($ftp);
            return false;
        }
        return $ftp;
    }
}
```

Comment: PASVのポートって開いてますか？